# DCPcrypt SHA512 does not match with PHP openssl_digest

Tags: php, c++, delphi-xe2, c++builder

working with project where I need to have SHA512 hash of string in C++ program and in PHP.

I'm using RAD Studio XE2 C++ builder with DCPCrypt library (ver. DCPcrypt v2 Beta 3 - RECOMMENDED).

Here is my C++ code, so very simple test program with Edit1(text input) and Edit2(hash output) and one button:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Edit2->Text = SHA512( Edit1->Text );

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
String __fastcall TForm1::SHA512(String input){

    if (input.Length() ) {
        TDCP_sha512 *sha512 = new TDCP_sha512(this);
        unsigned char array[192];

        String output = "";

        sha512->Init();
        sha512->UpdateStr( Edit1->Text );
        sha512->Final((void*)array);

        for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
            output += IntToHex(array[i], 2);
        }

        sha512->Free();

        return output.LowerCase();
    }
}
```

When I type "TEST" into Edit1 field and press button, I will have hash result:
0881048f3717a7cc363ca50e2dd7229efceb30786f0dc33b1b2cbcc3929055d00ed594f96127156aab01f30b6f6d28b100cbd7975e168bc39e50251d96c6beef

When I try same at PHP code:

```
<?PHP
    echo openssl_digest('TEST', 'sha512');
?>
```

This will give me totally different result:
7bfa95a688924c47c7d22381f20cc926f524beacb13f84e203d4bd8cb6ba2fce81c57a5f059bf3d509926487bde925b3bcee0635e4f7baeba054e5dba696b2bf

I can produce match if I compare string "1" in both ends, but after adding more letters, C++ code does not show same results.
When using some "online" sha512 forms I found from web I'm getting same results than in PHP code.

Any ideas?

Comment: is the text encoding the same, example: utf8

Comment: Won't fix the problem, but this line `sha512->UpdateStr( Edit1->Text );` shoud be `sha512->UpdateStr( input );`